# Height of whitespace above and below UIImage in UIImageView

Tags: swift3, uiimageview, uiimage, aspect-fit

Given a UIImageView using AspectFit how can I calculate the height of any whitespace above and below the UIImage?

Comment: please elaborate or give an example to clarify

Comment: Do some math based the frame size of the image view and the size of the image.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it easily when calculate the scale of the image:

```
let horizontalRatio = image.size.width / uiimageView.frame.size.width
let verticalSpacing = uiimageView.frame.size.height * horizontalRatio
```

And probably it is vertically in the middle

```
let whitespaceAbove = verticalSpacing / 2
let whitespaceBelow = verticalSpacing / 2
```